# Find the limit. (If an answer does not exist, enter DNE.) $\lim _{x→∞} (\sqrt{9x^2 + x} − 3x)$

Tags: calculus

I was following this explanation until the 5th step. The most important misunderstanding is if $1x/1x$ is $1$, and one can multiply a quotient by $1$ and not change its value. However from what I can see the $9x^2$ is being divided by $x^2$. How is that going to work? And why is that allowed? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because we are bringing the $1/x$ under the square root: for example,

$\sqrt{x}/x=\sqrt{x}/\sqrt{x^2}=\sqrt{x/x^2}=\sqrt{1/x}$.

Comment: You are bringing the 1/x under the square root; I understand that; but why then is the x squared under the radical. Are we assuming that anything going under the radical should not change its overall value thus the x must squared so as to keep the original radical unaffected?

Comment: It's because $x=\sqrt{x^2}$ (when $x\geq 0$).

Comment: That doesn't make any sense to me. Can you explain it a different way?

Comment: Okay. I sort of see it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing that

$$\sqrt{9x^2 + x} \cdot \frac{1}{x} = \sqrt{9x^2 + x} \cdot \sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}} = \sqrt{\frac{9x^2 + x}{x^2}} = \sqrt{\frac{9x^2}{x^2} + \frac{x}{x^2}}$$

for $x > 0$.

In case you're forgetting, $1/x = \sqrt{1/x^2}$ when $x > 0$ because for $x > 0$, $1/x$ is positive and $(1/x)^2 = 1/x^2$.